# reloading properties in a storm bolt

Tags: java, bigdata, apache-storm

I have some messages whose format will not change but data can change which I want to insert into MySQL db. So I want to create a properties file which can give me column names for the data received and the table name, so that I can create, edit the tables on the fly without restarting my topology. How is it possible to achieve something like that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It's not clear from your question. To do dynamic configuration, looking into leveraging zookeeper may be of value.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes, its not possible to change the wiring of bolts or spouts once the topology is submitted.

I am bit confused about how are you planning to receive these information dynamically from a property file. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is not for changing the wiring of bolts but rather for getting the column names in db to insert the data. So, I want to maintain an editable properties file.